# What does "bar hate" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The controversial law will also **bar hate** speech and harassment.

What does it mean in the example above?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you assumed **bar hate** was a single element. In the UK, *hate speech* is quite a common expression - is that not the case where you come from? I don't much care for the term; it smacks of downbeat journalese to me. But one certainly reads it quite a lot in these troubled times.

Comment: Bar hate: the stop on a pub crawl between bar sheven and bar fnine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I Don't know why I thought they would be one element! Maybe because I had not seen "hate speech" before though it totally makes sense.

Comment: @MT_Head: Quite Good!

Comment: @MT_Head: haha - it'd be a seasoned drinker who could make it to the ninth bar before barfing, especially if he was already slurring his speech two pubs before that! :)

Comment: I myself hate bar speech.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Bar" means "prohibit", so the sentence translates to:

> The controversial law will also prohibit hate speech and harassment.

Answer (score 4):

Controversial law (subject); will bar (verb); hate speech (object).

"Bar" in this context is a verb that means "forbid," or "hold back," (as in "bar the door.") It has nothing to do with taverns (which have "bars"), and that is probably why you're confused.